# how to push data into json file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i need to push my data into an external json file. When i reload the page, the new data should be in the list. Can someone help me?
here my code:

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    var user = {
        id: null,
        login: '',
        Vorname: '',
        Nachname: '',
        password: '',
        Admin: ''
    }

    $scope.editUser(user);
    $scope.titlePopup = "Benutzer erstellen";

    $scope.list.push(user);
}
```

this is the js file to get the data

thank you for your answers.

Comment: Simple but not answerable - too broad. In general you will need a server to write data into file, if this is what you want.

Comment: is it not able to make it with a push?

Comment: is it possible to make it without a server?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Can you provide more details about this

Comment: Do you want to add your user json as list json element

Comment: my users are saved in a json file with an Id, login, firstname, lastname, password and if he is an admin

Comment: "users": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "login": "NS",
            "Vorname": "Nicolas",
            "Nachname": "Suhner",
            "password": "wiga1",
            "isAdmin": "Ja"
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data ready, you can push it simply in below manners.
$scope.usersData = { id: '1', login: 'test' };

Comment: i saved my user in an var. can i push the var like this?

Comment: $socpe.list.push(user);

Comment: If you have your JSON into var then just assign it to scope variable like $scope.list = user;

Comment: And you can use LocalStorage to persist data while reloading the page.

Comment: but i need the data for longer time not just one reload is this possible without a server?

Comment: Nope, it is not possible without storing in database, because if you are storing into Local storage or cookies and cleared your browser's history or cookies you will lost your data.